# Presented calculation values are different when pasted into cells. Why?

Tags: vba

I am trying to get a calculated returned value to be pasted into a chosen cell, However, the returned value in the message box is different than the pasted value into the cell. Why is this?

```
Sub CalcmsgboxAcre()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim num As Double
    num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Enter The Number Of Hectares You Would Like To Calculate Into Acres ", Type:=1)
    MsgBox Format(num * 2.471054, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Acre's."
        num = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)
        If num = vbYes Then
            cell = Application.InputBox("Type In The Cell Reference")
            Range(cell).Value = num * 2.471054

        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a new value to num:

```
num = MsgBox (...)
```

So `vbYes` gets multiplied by the factor and then enters the cell.

Comment: Are so i needed to Dim Save and change Num to Save after the MSG format, you da man, thanks bro!